# Changin image opacity in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, image, opacity

Can someone please explain why this doesn't work:

```
    var MyImage = new Image();
    MyImage.src = "SomeImage.png";

    MyImage.style.opacity = 0.5;  // has no effect
    ctx.drawImage(MyImage,100,100);  // shows image with 1.0 opacity
```

I'm using firefox. The image file loads and works fine, just the opacity is missing. I'd rather have a solution without JQuery. I'd also like to change the opacity in a loop, so I think I can't use a CSS - solution

EDIT: The solution is found behind the link above, thank you.

I thought I might as well write the solution here also, in case it helps someone with similar questions.

For image opacity I must change the context global alpha.

For example:

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
ctx.drawImge(MyImg,X,Y);
ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0; // remember to reset the alpha value back to 1.0
```

For fade out effect on screen you can use an object like:

```
function ObjectToRender(Img, OpacityValue, X,Y){

this.Img = Img;
this.OpacityValue = OpacityValue;
this.X = X;
this.Y = Y;
}
```

then you can loop through the rendering, and drop the opacity by increments.

this example assumes that you have several obejcts like above to render, stored in an array "StuffToRender".

```
    // call this every time you want to decrease the opacity for each image

 for (var i=0; i<StuffToRender.length; i++){

       StuffToRender[i].OpacityValue -= 0.05; // this can be set as you like

       if (StuffToRender.OpacityValue > 0){

         ctx.globalAlpha = StuffToRender[i].OpacityValue;
         ctxdrawImage(StuffToRender[i].Img, StuffToRender[i].X,StuffToRender[i].Y);

       } else {StuffToRender.splice(i,1);}

    } 

    ctx.globaAlpha = 1;
```

the change in globalAlpha only affects image drawn after the change, not the ones drawn before. So, you can have several fade outs going on at the same time, with different opacities.

I also found some solutions with transparent div on top of the main Div, and the solution was to draw into the top layer div and change the alpha for that div only. Then one should change the Z-index of the divs or the dispaly mode. Changing these rapidly caused me some flickering, so I can't recommend that method. I don't know about the performance differences between these two ways.

Comment: Add a class to image and set style to that class. Not sure if its possible
   <class>.style.opacity = 0.5;

Comment: @amitmah — That won't help. The problem is not the appearance of the `<img>` element. The `<img>` element is never rendered. The syntax `<class>.style.opacity` is just plain nonsense.

Comment: @Quentin the syntax <class> is meant to be replaced with the element class. You can actually try it in firebug and it works.

Comment: @amitmah — http://jsbin.com/cinoyet/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @Quentin Try this in your URL:
document.querySelectorAll(".foo")[0].style.opacity = 0.1;

Comment: @amitmah — Which (a) isn't what you said and (b) won't help with MattJ's problem because it is trying to alter the opacity of an image being rendered on a canvas and not an actual element. (The img element exists only as a means to fetch the image data, the element itself is never rendered on the page).